# my str(float) gets broken on histogram dictionary conversion, how do I stop this?

Tags: python, dictionary, histogram

When attempting to histogram a list of numbers(in str formats) all of my numbers get broken up
for instance

```
a = ['1','1.5','2.5']
```

after running my histogram function
my dictionary looks like

```
{'1': 2, '2': 1, '5': 2, '.': 2}
```

my histogram function is

```
def histogram(a):
    d = dict()
    for c in a:
        d[c] = d.get(c,0)+1

    return d
```

I'm doing a project for school and have everything coded in, but when I get to doing the mode portion and I use numbers that aren't specifically int I get the above returns
How can I adjust/change this so it accepts the strings exactly as typed
Python 2.7 on Windows 7x64

Comment: python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 I can't replicate the problem

Comment: OSX 10.7 can't replicate the problem... did you have an extra loop in the original code, making you loop trough each char in the string?... because the result has 2x1, 1x2, 2x5. 2x'.'... which is a correct 'string' histogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The histgram function does work as it's written. If however you you inadvertently .join() your list your histogram with then histogram the resulting object. For instance... `t = ['1.0','2.0','2.5']` and 
`s = s.join(t)` s will then be == '1.02.02.5' and histogram(s) will count the decimals as values in the slice. My problem was that I had placed a .join() prior to calling histogram.
My appologies to anyone that wasted any real time on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert each string element to a float before passing it your histogram function.

```
a = ['1','1.5','2.5']

a = [float(i) for i in a]

def histogram(a):
    d = dict()
    for c in a:
        d[c] = d.get(c,0)+1

    return d

print histogram(a)
```

Comment: ok, let me try the float conversion and see what happens, the only thing I had in the original was a line... t = list(a), but I ended up not using that and removed it, other than that the histogram function is as it is, it worked on any list I fed it, whether str or int, just it broke the floats when they were strings.

Comment: Ok, a little more info, my program takes the input, does a function call to make sure the input is a number(returns either int or float based on input), makes a list of the returns until your done, then you can have it average, median, or mode the list(each is a seperate function call. Average and median work just fine and return ints or floats accordingly. When I get to mode, my mode function sorts the list, converts it back to str, then function calls histogram, this is when I get the broken floats. Then it builds a reverse dictionary, lists the keys, sorts the new list and prints the mode

Comment: p.s. I only get the broken floats in the program, not when I run histogram in the shell by itself as Stu wrote it. so basically I take a str, convert it to int or float, make a list of these, then convert back to str then histogram.

Comment: Sorry for all these posts, after playing around in shell I figured out what my problem was, it's not in histogram. My problem occurs when I try to convert my int/float list back to str. So I have to adjust my program a little to adjust for this. The list I gave you wasn't what my program was actually sending to histogram. It was actually sending a list of stringed ints. So, before I rewrite a large portion of my program, is there a simple way to convert them to str without losing the decimals?

Comment: glad you got it sorted!  Update your question to describe what the problem was and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an error in your list definition. Running your code I get

```
{'1': 1, '1.5': 1, '2.5': 1}
```

If I change the definition of `a` from

```
a = ['1','1.5','2.5']
```

to

```
a = '1' '1.5' '2.5'
```

I get the output you showed us.

So please double check how your list is defined.

Comment: I forgot to scroll down and didn't see these posts. Here's what I determined, my first list is the inputs converted from str to float or int(checks length then int(input) or float(input) and returns the int or float, then generates a list of these. Histogram requires str so I try to convert the list back to str and that is when the problem happens. a = [str(n) for n in a] returns the above list as ['1','1','2']. So either I need to not convert before I list, or find a better way to convert back to str

Comment: Nevermind, my problem was in some obscure .join statement I didn't notice somewhere else in my program.

Comment: P.S. Thanks to everyone for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
>>> a = ['1','1.5','2.5']
>>> dict.fromkeys(a, 0)
{'1': 0, '1.5': 0, '2.5': 0}
```

Now you can iterate over keys to set the corresponding value.

I have used the following dict comprehension to reduce my work.

```
>>> {key: float(key)+1 for key in a}
{'1': 2.0, '1.5': 2.5, '2.5': 3.5}
```

enjoy :)